# SSL Client For Row Tcp/Ip in iphone

Tags: iphone, ssl, sockets, tcp

i want to make a  client of SSL Server Socket in iphone but i cannot find any API in iPhone.
i have valid certificate file with password

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/)?